# How do I go to a URL with a query string programmatically in Meteor using Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I need to change my route programmatically and I want to include a query string. Can someone give me some insight on the syntax to do this?

Here is some code that does not work, but I would like something like this:

```
var queryString = '&status=closed&date_range=recent
Router.go('grid.sort', {query:queryString});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [path-functions section](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#path-functions-and-helpers) of the docs. This should work:

```js
Router.go('grid.sort', {}, {
  query: {
    status: 'closed',
    date_range: 'recent'
  }
});
```

Comment: Link update: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/Guide.md#path-and-link-template-helpers